# how stackoverflow handles pub/sub redis message correctly?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

[According to this architecture doc,](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) stackoverflow uses L1 (in memory) and L2 (redis) cache, then use Pub/Sub message to sync between instances and invalidate local caches.

I am trying to do the same thing for my site by using the stackexchange.redis library. However, when I put subscriber in startup code (global.asax), some times it won't respond to the messages I publish and the behavior is bit random. The testing code is something I directly copied from the doc.

```
sub.Subscribe("messages", (channel, message) => {
    Console.WriteLine((string)message);
});
```

I am wondering if stackoverflow ever sees the same problem or maybe other people has some better ideas?